# Unable to apply changes for Realtek Driver update?

Tags: drivers, realtek

How can I fix this driver update issue?
[image: Driver update issue]

Comment: What changes? If already in use then it you won't need to change anything.

Comment: Is your wireless working? If so, there is nothing to do. We see no issue that needs to be fixed.

Comment: Yes my Wifi is not working as you can see the device is not working so when I try to change the driver to DKMS driver I'm unable to apply the changes...I'm quite new to Linux so trying to figure things out

Answer (score 0):

You need to have a temporary internet connection to install the drivers (Ethernet or USB tethering).